# How to take a part of content in xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have parsed and XML file using python. In one of the tags it has been written an ID and then a sequence of amino acids. I just want to get the amino acid sequence and not the ID.
this is what the tag looks like:

```
  <sequences>
    <sequence format="FASTA">&gt;DB00001 sequence
LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIP
EEYLQ</sequence>
  </sequences>
```

When i use this code:

```
drug.find('sequences').find('sequence').text
```

it prints:

```
>DB00001 sequence
LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIP
EEYLQ
```

But i want to print only `LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIPEEYLQ`

I appreciate answers which solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the module `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the XML content, find the `<sequence>` element, extract its text content, and then process it to get the desired amino acid sequence without the ID.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Sample XML content
xml_content = '''
<sequences>
  <sequence format="FASTA">&gt;DB00001 sequence
LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIP
EEYLQ</sequence>
</sequences>
'''

# Parse the XML content
root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)

# Find the sequence element and extract the text
sequence_element = root.find('.//sequence')
sequence_text = sequence_element.text.strip().split('\n', 1)[1].replace('\n', '')

print(sequence_text)
```

Output:

```
LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIPEEYLQ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() method to get the amino acid sequence.

```
text = drug.find('sequences').find('sequence').text
print(text.split("sequence")[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """\
  <sequences>
    <sequence format="FASTA">&gt;DB00001 sequence
LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIP
EEYLQ</sequence>
  </sequences>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

for s in soup.select('sequences sequence[format="FASTA"]'):
    t = "".join(s.get_text(strip=True).splitlines()[1:])
    print(t)
```

Prints:

```
LTYTDCTESGQNLCLCEGSNVCGQGNKCILGSDGEKNQCVTGEGTPKPQSHNDGDFEEIPEEYLQ
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and reply. but the other answer was much closer to my goal